# Delphi using TNetHTTPClient: how to give the final url after redirections?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I use, with Delphi 10.3.1, a TNetHTTPClient with GET command and I need to get the final URL after a page redirection(s).
Is there any property or function for it ? 
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's no direct (public) access to request instance associated with response. A hacky solution relies on:

1. `IHTTPResponse` returned is implemented by `THTTPResponse` (implementation detail)
2. protected access to `FRequest` field of `THTTPResponse`

Then you can use following code to access request instance:

```
type
  THTTPResponseAccess = class(THTTPResponse);

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response: THTTPResponse;
  Request: IURLRequest;
begin
  Response := NetHTTPClient1.Get('http://google.com') as THTTPResponse;
  Request := THTTPResponseAccess(Response).FRequest;
  ShowMessage(Request.URL.ToString);
end;
```

Output is:

```
http://www.google.com/
```